# независимые нисходящие подключения

Tags: java

Всем доброго времени суток.
У меня не много опыта в java разработке, поэтому не судите строго.
Есть вопрос, ответ на который я не нашел на просторах интернета, точнее есть информация, но неоднозначная или я попросту не могу с ней разобраться. Нужно реализовать низходящие подключения, напишу весь текст задания чтоб было понятнее:

**Решение должно предоставлять http RestfulAPI.
Конечная точка «/ flight» должна ответить информацией о рейсе.
Данные запроса содержат «дату», «коды аэропортов вылета и прилета».
Данные ответа должны содержать «номер рейса». Между запросом и ответом вам
необходимо реализовать пять независимых нисходящих подключений, каждое из которых может занять
500-800 мс. Имитируйте эти ответы с искусственной случайной задержкой. Предположим, «номер рейса»
можно менять раз в 24 часа.
SLA составляет 850 мс, нагрузка может варьироваться: от 1К до 50К запросов в секунду.
Конечная точка «/ цена» должна принимать «номер рейса и дату» в качестве параметра и возвращать
"цена". Предположим, что «правила механизма ценообразования» (имитируйте этот объект), занимающие 3 ГБ ОЗУ - вам необходимо
сохранить в памяти.
SLA - 50 мс, нагрузка - около 50 запросов в день.**

Направьте меня пожалуйста куда "копать" а именно " Между запросом и ответом вам необходимо реализовать пять независимых нисходящих подключений" не могу разобраться как реализовать низходящие подключения, теории начитался много, а вот с практикой проблема.

Заранее всем спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Вам не нужно реализовывать подключения, вам нужно их имитировать. Имхо, вам надо Thread.Sleep поставить 5 раз в коде (хз почему 5, а не 1)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Получаеться нужно просто создать функцию с необходимой логикой, куда обратиться по API фронт и имитировать просто задержку? Я предположил что это что-то похожее на https://developer.liveswitch.io/liveswitch-cloud/guides/sfu-connection.html?tabs=tabid-4 и нужно использовать Channel. Про задержку в задании написано уже позже "Имитируйте эти ответы с искусственной случайной задержкой". Скажите, почему Вы это подключения посчитали просто задержкой,

Comment: Если к кому то обращаетесь, упоминайте ник вот так @nonsense. Я посчитал задержкой поэтому `Имитируйте эти ответы с искусственной случайной задержкой.`